# Peculiar situation inside an if loop

Tags: php, if-statement

I find myself in a very very peculiar situation . The issue is that the function that I am trying to call inside an if loop does not work . But if I call the same function without the if loop it works fine . **$this->build($passed_menu_id, $id_link);**. The **if** condition works absolutely fine because echo "Hello" gets printed . This means it is going inside the loop but not executing the function .

This Scenario is working perfectly fine

```
function Menu($passed_menu_id, $id_link) {
        $this->array_collection = array();
        $this->menu_collection = array();
        $this->menu_id = $this->_pickMenuId($passed_menu_id);
        $this->build($passed_menu_id, $id_link);
        }
```

This scenario does not work

```
 function Menu($passed_menu_id, $id_link) {
        $this->array_collection = array();
        $this->menu_collection = array();
        $this->menu_id = $this->_pickMenuId($passed_menu_id);
        if($this->menu_id==1003){
            echo "Hello";
            $this->build($passed_menu_id, $id_link);
        }
```

Thanks for your time in advance

Comment: There is no such thing as an if-loop. There is no loop at all in your code

Comment: Kindly check the second scenario

Comment: Have you tried to check for a different menu_id? Assuming that $this->build() e.g. fetches data from an database, maybe there is no data available for this ID?

Comment: @Justin: it's an if condition, not an if loop. Loop implies doing something more than once.

Comment: @Sutuma .. I checked it . The condition is getting satisfied .

Answer (score 1):

In your second scenario you are missing a `}`: It should be

```
 function Menu($passed_menu_id, $id_link) {
        $this->array_collection = array();
        $this->menu_collection = array();
        $this->menu_id = $this->_pickMenuId($passed_menu_id);
        if($this->menu_id==1003){
            echo "Hello";
            $this->build($passed_menu_id, $id_link);
        }  // This is missing
        }
```

Other than that there is nothing in the code which should stop that `if` from functioning the way it should

Comment: Put your echo after `build` and see if its same?

Comment: Yes its the same . Hello is getting printed

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps there is something in the build function that does not meet the "if" condition?  Can you post the build function code?